# Custom Rest API in Alfresco activi 5.* or 6.*

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I have written custom rest service which will return both tasks and variables with in a single rest call. Now I want to integrate this rest api with alfresco activiti rest api. 
Found url: http://docs.alfresco.com/process-services1.6/topics/custom_rest_endpoints.html
but after building the jar and putting it in web-inf/lib, firing a corresponding rest call is giving 404. 
please suggest me how can add custom rest endpoint/service to the existing activiti rest service and how to access that?

Comment: I guess we are going to need your webservice descriptor, and the position you put it in your projet.

Comment: @Akah, As I am using Rest service, I don't have wsdl. I have '@restcontroller','@requestmapping' spring mvc annotations.

Comment: since, I don't have edit access I am not able to paste the entire controller class in the comments section.      
 '@Controller'
'@RequestMapping'("/enterprise/test")
public class WorkListItemController {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkListItemController.class);
  '@Autowired'
 private WorkListItemService workListItemService;
   '@RequestMapping'(value = "/getWorkListItems", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public  ResponseEntity getWorkListItems('@RequestBody'WorkListItemRequestVO workListItemRequest)  {

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using Spring annotations to register your ReST controller.
Are you certain the controller class is being scanned?

When the controller registers you should get a log entry similar the the following in your server logs:

05:01:05,997 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/runtime/tasks/{taskId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void org.flowable.rest.service.api.runtime.task.TaskResource.deleteTask(java.lang.String,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

If you don't have such a log entry, your controller class isn't being registered and likely isn't being scanned.

Might be worth checking.
Greg

Comment: you are correct. My custom uri is not being scanned on tomcat boot up. I can see all the default uris(like /repository/*, identity/*,/runtime/* etc) . can you help me to troubleshoot ?

Comment: What are your ComponentScan settings?

Comment: so, just to brief I had simple web app rest that is built on maven for my custom rest api project. it has web.xml,spring-context.xml etc. I had the component scan in that as "com.activiti.rest.api". the web app standalone is working. but when I jar it, I see only .class and properties in that archive.